# How to insert a list of tokenised values and columns to a dataframe in python in each iteration of a loop

Tags: python, data-science

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
    output=[]
    data= str(df1.iloc[i].NOTE)
    data1=data.lower()
    data1 = word_tokenize(data1)
    for words in data1:
        if words not in stop_words:
            output.append(words)
        if any(words.isdigit() for words in output):
            output.remove(words)
    print(df1.iloc[i].AMRI_PRESCRIPTION_ID,df1.iloc[i].AMRI_CLINICAL_NOTE_Q_ID,output)
```

Here `output` is a list of `tokenized` values.
Above print gives me the result:

```
127 1 ['second', 'episode', 'fever', 'last', 'week']
```

I need to keep this value in a dataframe and next the same dataframe to a table in my database. Any help please.

Comment: Please update this question such that it contains a [MCVE]. I don't see any values, I don't see the expected dataframe, and I can't copy-paste any runnable code into my interpreter to help you.

Comment: @timgeb Here AMRI_PRESCRIPTION_ID =127, AMRI_CLINICAL_NOTE_Q_ID =1 and output(list of tokenised values)=['second', 'episode', 'fever', 'last', 'week']. I need to  create a dataframe with the above mentioned columns and insert it to a table.